# DAG running automatically when I upload it

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am facing a problem with my airflow DAGs: I need to upload some DAGs but I need they to run ONLY on the time on the schedule, but some times that is not what is happening, I will give you a sample code:

```
from airflow import models
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'depends_on_past': False
}

with models.DAG(
    "schedule_test",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="30 19 * * *",
    catchup = False

) as dag:

operator_1 = DummyOperator(task_id='operator_1')
operator_2 = DummyOperator(task_id='operator_2')

operator_1 >> operator_2
```

If I upload this code at 19:00 (before the time on the schedule), it wont run right away, and will work just as expected, running at 19:30.

But if I upload this code at 20:00 (after the time on the schedule), it will execute right away, but it will give me a wrong output, i need it to run only at 19:30.

Could anyone assist me in resolving this problem?